# Why does Visual Studio 2012 prevent saving aspx pages that have not been validated?

Tags: asp.net, validation, visual-studio-2012, settings, resharper

My company recently migrated to Visual Studio 2012 and I am using it to develop web application using ASPX pages. The pages are split with the C# in a code-behind file. After using 2012 for a couple weeks now, I noticed something: if my ASPX page does not correctly validate to the HTML5 standard (i.e. I am missing a closing tag somewhere), the page will not save. This problem does not occur in the code-behind file, nor does it occur on Razor pages.

I briefly looked through the standard Visual Studio settings pages, but cannot find a setting to allow invalid code to be saved. I also have Resharper installed (as well as the Productivity Power Tools), but cannot find a setting in either of those extensions that seem to relate to my issue. If it matters, the project I am working on is part of a TFS solution.

Has anyone else experienced this issue? If so, does anyone know of a setting that might have caused this that I may be overlooking?

**Update:** Since posting this, I have noticed that I am unable to save even after the page has been validated. It can take up to a minute before Visual Studio allows me to save the page. The length of time may be related to the amount of text that I entered before trying to save.

**Update 2:** After talking to a coworker who has a similar set of extensions, I determined that Resharper must be causing the problem. If anyone knows of a Resharper 7 setting that may be causing this, please let me know. I can't tell if this is a bug or an intended feature.

**Final Update:** Thank you to all who offered assistance, but after installing the Visual Studio Update 1, I no longer notice the problem. It seems to have been a bug that was fixed with the update.

Comment: Sounds pretty sweet to me. Once you figure out how to turn that off let me know so I can turn it on!

Comment: Are you sure?  That doesn't make any sense.  Maybe the file is just read-only due to source control protection.  I can save all my files anytime.

Comment: "the page will not save" - do you get an error? A dialog? A disabled menu item?

Comment: @hunter It suppose that it would be nice to prevent errors from occurring on the page, but I am a chronic saver - my left hand defaults to the Ctrl-Shift-S position. Because of this, when the page doesn't save my brain has a little freak-out.

Comment: @AakashM There is no error, the star in the tab simply will not go away.

Comment: @SteveWellens I can save once the built-in html5 validation checks out ok, but not if the page is 'invalid'

Comment: Do you have any third party Visual Studio add-ons that could be causing this?  Never mind, I see you have: Resharper and Productivity Power Tools.  I would try disabling them to see if they are the perpetrators.

Comment: In addition, I cannot save until some delay after the page has been validated.

Comment: @SteveWellens The only intrusive extension I have installed is Resharper. I also have Productivity Power Tools installed (which changes the '*' icon on the tab to a red dot), but I have never experienced this in VS2010.

Comment: @HBennet - I don't think VS2012 is doing it.  It doesn't on my box.

Comment: @SteveWellens It must be Resharper 7 that is causing the save problem. One of my co-workers has almost the same set of extensions installed, except Resharper, but his env isn't having the same problem.

Comment: It's definitely not ReSharper's fault. You can check it by disabling it in Tools->Options->ReSharper.

Comment: @derigel How do you know that it is not ReSharper's fault, have you experienced this same issue without RS installed?

Comment: @HBennet, did you try to disable ReSharper?

Comment: @derigel I did not, but I recently installed the Visual Studio 2012 update 1 and noticed the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the final update section in the question, after installing the Visual Studio Update 1, I no longer notice the problem. It seems to have been a bug that was fixed with the update. Problem resolved!

Comment: I'm on Update 4 and I have the problem!

Comment: @ChadD Glad to see I wasn't the only one... Every now and then, the problem occurs again, but the problem went away for the most part after the Update 1. As you can see, I was never able to find a solution. Let me know if you are able to figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Grrr, still happening in 2015, and I don't even have ReSharper or Productivity Power Tools installed.  I found a workaround.  I quit VS, said YES to saving the items in the popup, reopened it, and found that they were saved to older statuses.  I re-changed the code, saved (took many seconds but probably less than a minute), and recompiled, and the changes took this time.

It was nice that when I quit and saved (unsuccessfully), it at least showed that the code was in an older state, instead of showing the newer code with a perpetual asterisk.

I'd never seen this before, and hope never to again.